# SSIS Import CSV data just one time

Tags: ssis

I'm planning to import csv file into oledb destination just one time and should do the rest of the process. Process should check for data existence and move on with rest of the process. How would i do this.

Comment: I know i can create 2 packages to do this but i need to find a way to do in single package.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you be more specific about the steps you're trying to implement? And if you can already do it in two packages then what difficulty do you have combining the two packages into one?